# Dilate/Erode image without changing size

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to write my own dilate and erode functions in matlab. I have an implementation that works, but it changes the size of the output image.

This is what I have:

Erode

```
function eroded = erode(X) 
eroded = col2im(min(im2col(X, [3 3])), [3 3], size(X));
end
```

Dilate

```
function dilated = dilate(X) 
dilated = col2im(max(im2col(X, [3 3])), [3 3], size(X));
end
```

these work visually, but when I try to overlay the regions made with them it gets messed up because the dimensions of the image matrix had changed. I have identified that the problem is in `col2im` or `im2col`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Playing around with it I found that it is likely associated with how `min` and `max` reduce the size of the columns in the transformed matrix to 1.

Comment: the 2nd function should be `function  f= Dilate(X) `... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to be considering the boundary conditions in your implementation.

To do this, you will most likely not be able to have your function be written in one line. You can do one of two things: 1) create a separate filter to apply to the edges and then append your output with these values, or 2) ignore the boundaries and zero-pad, or 3) ignore the boundaries and append with the values from the original image.

Note: Although you are writing your own functions, an effective built-in Matlab function would be as follows:

```
eroded = imerode(X,[1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1]);
```

And for dilation:

```
dilated = imdilate(X,[1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1]);
```